# How to add bank details of a customer in stripe using node js

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to add bank details of a particular customer in stripe through nodejs but facing issue in sending the data.I was following the stripe documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_bank_accounts/create

In my case it is throwing below error:

Error: Received unknown parameters: account_holder_name, account_holder_type, customer

Hence if you could please help me resolve this issue.

please find below code:

```
app.post('/addbankaccountdetails', async function(req,res) {

  const bankAccount = await stripe.customers.createSource(
    'cus_M4zhLpZUB456Ef',
    {
      source: {
      object: 'source',
      account_holder_name: 'Rakesh Aggarwal',
      account_holder_type: 'individual',
      customer: 'cus_M4zhLpZUB456Ef'
    }
  }
  );
  res.status(200).send();  
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet to create a bank account for a customer using [`createSource()`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_bank_accounts/create):

```
const bankAccount = await stripe.customers.createSource('cus_xxx', {
  bank_account: {
    object: "bank_account", 
    account_holder_name: "Foo Bar", 
    account_holder_type: "individual",  
    account_number: "000123456789", 
    routing_number: "110000000", 
    country: "US", 
    currency: "usd",
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the docs for the method you're trying to use: https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/create?lang=node#create_card-source

The parameters you're trying to use aren't listed in the docs for that method.